# highcharts tick position incorrect when categories specified

Tags: highcharts, categories

please take a look at this graph which displays as expected (i.e. ticks are at the specified positions):

http://jsfiddle.net/a3ZrC/3/

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositions: [1, 3, 4, 5, 10],
    gridLineWidth: '1',
    lineWidth: 1
    //tickPosition: 'outside'       
},
```

Now, if I specify categories, the tick positions (and grid) change, they are no longer on the label, see:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3ZrC/4/

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositions: [1, 3, 4, 5, 10],
    categories: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve'],
    gridLineWidth: '1',
    lineWidth: 1
    //tickPosition: 'outside'       
},
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Cheers,

Tony.

Comment: Hmm, I can see this issue with all sorts of charts, like this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tuvC/185/

notice how the lines aren't in the correct positions. Delete the categories section under xAxis and it displays the grid properly.
Note that if you then click the button to setCategories, it DOES display correctly!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guess you missed a trick here. You can specify the [**tickmarkPlacement**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) option .

It defaults to `between`. Specify it as `on` to get the results as you desired.

```
xAxis: {            
        tickPositions: [1, 3, 4, 5, 10],
        categories: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve'],
        gridLineWidth: '1',
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    },
```

[`Fiddled`](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/a3ZrC/6/) version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
Oddly, I also found that if I DON'T add categories when I create the chart, but issue this command immediatly after:
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([...]);
Then it would work correctly. I guess SOMETIMES the default for tickmarkPlacement is default and for other situation's it's on.

Comment: Thank for your answer.